# Clear multiple cell highlight on button click jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have a `jqgrid` in which i have multiple cell selected(Ctrl key) which is in yellow highlight.

Now on a button click i have to clear all the cell highlighted.But if a row is selected it should be the same. Need only the cell highlight to be removed.

Any possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems be small modification of the answer on your previous question. If `mySelection` parameter holds the information about selected cells then one can unselect the cells in the following event handler:

```js
$("#clearCellSelection").button().click(function () {
    var key, item, $td, rows = $grid[0].rows, p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam"),
        mySelection = p.mySelection,
        idPrefix = p.idPrefix;

    // click without Ctrl key pressed
    // we need unselect all
    for (key in mySelection) {
        if (mySelection.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            item = mySelection[key];
            $td = $(rows.namedItem(idPrefix + item.id).cells[item.indexOfColumn]);
            $td.removeClass("ui-state-highlight").removeAttr("aria-selected");
        }
    }
    p.mySelection = {};
});
```

The corresponding modified demo is [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/cellMultiselect1.htm).

One should be careful if the grid contains `sortable: true` option or if `columnChooser` allows the user to change the order of the columns. In the case one can't use `indexOfColumn` property of the selected cell information. Instead of that one have to use `colName` property and find the index of the column with the name `colName` in `colModel`. The index should be used instead of `indexOfColumn`.

Comment: Simply superb Oleg. I'm glad that you rembered the last question that i have asked u. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Can you please look into this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009476/retain-filter-text-in-filter-toolbar-on-grid-reload