# Retain filter text in filter toolbar on grid reload

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using `jqgrid` in which i'm trying to retain the filter text after the grid reload.

I have cell update functionality,

//Code:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateComments", "Home")',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: { 'resultData': filterResult, 'action': postdata.oper },
    type: 'POST',
    success: OnCompleteComments,
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        if (xhr.statusText == "Session TimeOut/UnAuthorized") {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("LogOut", "Account")';
        }
        else
            alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
//After update Load the grid.
function OnCompleteComments(result) {

    myfilter = $('#TransactionsGrid').jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData").filters;
    Loadgrid($('#TransactionsGrid').getGridParam('page'));

}
```

After the successful udpate of the cell i'm reloading the grid for the cell to reflect the udpated values. In the `OnComplete` i'm getting the filter assigned to a golbally declared variable(myfilter).

//Grid:

```
datatype: 'local',
hoverrows: false,
colNames: colHeader,
colModel: colname,
localReader: { id: 'TransactionId' },
rowNum: 10,
hidegrid: false,
rownumbers: true,
pager: '#TransactionsGridPager',
viewrecords: true,
caption: "Transaction Details",
height: 'auto',
scrollOffset: 0,
page: PageNumber,
gridview: true,
shrinkToFit: true,
autoencode: true,
ignoreCase: true,
mySelection: {},
onInitGrid: function () {
    // get reference to parameters
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");

    // set data parameter
    p.data = gridData.BuildTransactionsDataTable;

},
```

In grid reload(`ajax` function is called), once the grid is loaded i'm re assigning the filter. In this place i'm getting the filtered results in the grid exactly bu the text which i used to filter the results is not in the filter toolbar. Its empty.

GridReload(Retain filter):

```
jQuery("#TransactionsGrid").jqGrid({
  });
 if (myfilter) {
      var searchFiler = JSON.parse(myfilter).rules[0].data, grid = $("#TransactionsGrid"), f;
      if (searchFiler.length === 0) {
          grid[0].p.search = false;
          $.extend(grid[0].p.postData, { filters: "" });
      }
      f = { groupOp: "OR", rules: [] };
      f.rules.push({ field: JSON.parse(myfilter).rules[0].field, op: "cn", data: searchFiler });

      grid[0].p.search = true;
      $.extend(grid[0].p.postData, { filters: JSON.stringify(f) });
      grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1, current: true }]);
  }
```

Now i need the filtered text to be retained in the filter toolbar. how can i achieve this?

Comment: The code is unclear for me. It's not important just to have the code of `GridReload`. The most important *when* (where) the function `GridReload` will be called. If you call it **in the correct place** it will work. You included the fragment "cell update" (which have small bug by the way: the usage of `datatype` instead of `dataType`), but you don't show which editing mode you use, in how (where) you fill the grid, how (where) you make the "cell update". Moreover it's unclear why the grid need be reloaded after the cell update. jqGrid update the cell *automatically*.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks for your idea. Got this done by setting manually. Can you please look into this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059762/delete-no-url-is-set-in-jqgrid

Comment: @Oleg: Had a time to look into this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059762/delete-no-url-is-set-in-jqgrid