# Delete, No url is set in jqgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm using `jqgrid` and when deleting a row in the grid i get the alert "`Delete selected record?`" and when i click ok i have written a code in `onClickSubmit` to make a `ajax` call to the controller which takes some parameters and delete the record. The functionality works fine.

But when i click "`Delete`" button in the alert i get an error "`No url is set`". Now, i have a `url` inside my `ajax` call which does the function. Why is the error thrown?

jqGrid:

```
var selectedRowId = "125";

     $("#AttachmentsGrid").jqGrid({

         url: '@Url.Action("LoadTransactionAttachments", "Home")',
         postData: { 'transactionId': selectedRowId },
         mtype: 'GET',
         datatype: 'json',
         jsonReader: {
             id: 'AttachmentId',
             repeatitems: false
         },
         height: 'auto',
         hidegrid: false,
         rownumbers: true,
         autowidth: true,
         shrinkToFit: false,
         rowNum: 10,
         pager: '#AttachmentsPager',
         caption: "Attachments",
         colNames: ['AttachmentName'],
         colModel: [{ name: 'AttachmentName', index: 'AttachmentName', formatter: imageFormatter, unformat: imageUnFormatter }],
         beforeRequest: function () {
             responsive_jqgrid($(".jqGrid"));
         },
         onSelectRow: function (id) {

             var statusId;
             attachmentId = id;
             var selectValues = jQuery('#AttachmentsGrid').jqGrid('getRowData', id);

             attachmentName = selectValues.AttachmentName;

             if (accessLevel.HasDeleteAttachmentAccess == true)
                 $("#del_AttachmentsGrid").show();
             else
                 $("#del_AttachmentsGrid").hide();

         },
         loadComplete: function () {
             UnBlockUI();
         }
     });

     jQuery("#AttachmentsGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#AttachmentsPager', {
         edit: false, add: false, del: true, search: false, refresh: true, refreshtext: ""
     }, {}, {}, {

        // url: '@Url.Action("UpdateDummyData", "Home")',

         // Delete attachment event.
         onclickSubmit: function (response, postData) {

             $.ajax({
                 url: '@Url.Action("DeleteSelectedTransactionAttachment", "Home")',
      datatype: 'json',
      data: { 'attachmentId': JSON.stringify(postData), 'attachmentName': attachmentName, 'transactionId': selectedRowId },
      type: 'POST',
      success: OnCompleteDeleteAttachments,
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
          if (xhr.statusText == "Session TimeOut/UnAuthorized") {
              alert(xhr.statusText);
              window.location.href = '@Url.Action("LogOut", "Account")';
          }
          else
              alert(xhr.responseText);
      }
  });
```

It works when i give some Dummy url in delete method which i dont need. I need another way to solve this.?

**FYI**, This happens for me also during the edit of a row using `form editing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you try to use Delete in a wrong way. What you do is making Ajax request to `'@Url.Action("DeleteSelectedTransactionAttachment", "Home")'` with some additional data, do some unknown additional action inside of `OnCompleteDeleteAttachments` in case of successful deleting and do additional error handling in case of `"Session TimeOut/UnAuthorized"` error in `statusText`.

I think that correct implementation should looks more as the following

```
jQuery("#AttachmentsGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#AttachmentsPager', {
         edit: false, add: false, search: false, refreshtext: ""
    }, {}, {}, {
    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteSelectedTransactionAttachment", "Home")',
    serializeDelData: function (postData) {
        return {
            attachmentId: JSON.stringify(postData),
            attachmentName: attachmentName,
            transactionId: selectedRowId
        }
    },
    errorTextFormat: function (xhr) {
        if (xhr.statusText == "Session TimeOut/UnAuthorized") {
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("LogOut", "Account")';
        } else {
            return xhr.responseText;
        }
    },
    afterSubmit: OnCompleteDeleteAttachments
});
```